font size is not working when using from html
I have a textview in an Android application. I want to set the textview's value from HTML. For example, I get a value like this:
<span style="font-family:'Roboto-Regular'; font-size:13px; color:#383838 \">102,</span>
<span style="font-family:'Roboto-Regular'; font-size:11px; color:#383838 \">60 TL</span> 

and I want to set the textview's value using the fromhtml() method. The color tag is working perfectly, but the font-size tag is not working - I expect the text after the comma to be small, but the tag doesn't change the text size at all.

Html.fromHtml() does not handle arbitrary HTML, let alone arbitrary CSS. While it does support color in a style attribute (at least on modern versions of Android), it does not support font-size or font-family. You will need to handle those yourself by other means.
